# Inheritance problem: calling parent construct function in subclass

Tags: php, inheritance, domdocument, extends, construct

I have a class named **Display** which extends class **Layout**, which extends class **DOMDocument**. I get: *Fatal error: Call to a member function loadHTMLFile() on a non-object.* Code as follows:

*In index.php :*

```
 $dom = new Display();
 $dom->displayData();
```

*In Display.php :*

```
class Display extends Layout {

    public function displayData(){

    $dom = parent::__construct();
    $dom->loadHTMLfile("afile.html");
    echo $dom->saveHTML();

    }

}
```

**My question is:** When I call **parent::__construct()** ,  isn't this the same as using "**new DOMDocument**", since the Display class extends Layout and DOMDocument?Thanks

Comment: You mix `$dom` with `$this` and don't call `parent::__construct()` if not inside the class self `__construct()` method, that makes no sense. [joakimdahlstrom has the code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300917/inheritance-problem-calling-parent-construct-function-in-subclass/6300982#6300982).

Comment: Ah and the answer to your question is: No.

Comment: Yeah, I got it, I got it, how do I show the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `loadHTMLfile` function in your parent class, the subclass will inherit it. So you should be able to do:

```
class Display extends Layout {

    public function displayData(){

        $this->loadHTMLfile("afile.html");
        echo $this->saveHTML();

    }

}
```

Comment: Oh ok, I got it, there is not even need to instantiate the class, I don't know why I was confused about this. Thank you my brother.

Answer (score 3):

`__construct()` is a magic method that is called when you instantiate the object.

Calling it is *not* the same as using the `new` operator.

In my experience, I have only ever used `parent::__construct()` inside of the `__construct()` of a subclass when I need the parent's constructor called.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the same because constructor in php **doesn't return anything**

Answer (score 1):

You typically call the parent's constructor inside the subclass's constructor.  You're calling it in the `displayData()` method.  It is only necessary to call the parent's constructor explicitly in the subclass constructor if you do additional work in the subclass constructor.  Inheriting it directly without changes means you needn't call the parent constructor.

Calling the parent constructor will not return a value (object), as instantiating the object would.